# How to easily find the coefficients of a cubic polynomial and its plot for the given 4 points

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, interpolation

Given 4 points as `points = {{0, 4}, {1, 0}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}};`. I want to find the coefficients of `f[x_] := a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d;` and its plot.

How to solve this in Mathematica easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `LinearSolve`

```
A = CoefficientArrays[f@points[[All, 1]], {a, b, c, d}] //Last;
B = points[[All, 2]];
```

> $A=\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  8 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
>  27 & 9 & 3 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)        \qquad   B=\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  4 \\
>  0 \\
>  -1 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
LinearSolve[A, B]
```

> {-(1/6), 2, -(35/6), 4}

Answer (score 5):

```
fit = FindFit[points, f[x], {a, b, c, d}, x]
```

> {a -> -0.166667, b -> 2., c -> -5.83333, d -> 4.}

```
Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. fit], {x, 0, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@points}]
```

[image]

To get exact results, you can use

```
Rationalize[fit]
```

> {a -> -(1/6), b -> 2, c -> -(35/6), d -> 4}

Alternatively, you can use `Reduce` or `Solve` (as in rhermans's answer) with alternative specification of the first argument:

```
ToRules @ Reduce[f /@ points[[All, 1]] == points[[All, 2]]] (* or *)
Solve[f /@ points[[All, 1]] == points[[All, 2]], {a, b, c, d}][[1]]
```

> {a -> -(1/6), b -> 2, c -> -(35/6), d -> 4}

Comment: Could you make the coefficients in exact forms?

Comment: @FriendlyGhost,  you can use `Rationalize[fit]` to get `{a -> -(1/6), b -> 2, c -> -(35/6), d -> 4}`

Comment: @FriendlyGhost Four points define the polynomial unambiguously, so an exact solution is possible solving the system of equations, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Four points define the polynomial unambiguously, not fitting is necesary, so for an exact solution I would do a system of equations and use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
points = {{0, 4}, {1, 0}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}}
(* {{0, 4}, {1, 0}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}} *)

f[x_] := a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d


(f[#1] == #2) & @@@ points
(* 
 {
   d == 4, 
   a + b + c + d == 0, 
   8 a + 4 b + 2 c + d == -1, 
   27 a + 9 b + 3 c + d == 0
  }
*)


Solve[
 (f[#1] == #2) & @@@ points
 , {a, b, c, d}
 ]
(* {{a -> -(1/6), b -> 2, c -> -(35/6), d -> 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial):

```
Expand @ InterpolatingPolynomial[
    {{0,4},{1,0},{2,-1},{3,0}},
    x
]
```

> 4 - (35 x)/6 + 2 x^2 - x^3/6